# How to change the Bundle Identifier in iTunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I changed the bundle identifier of my app after a few updates, and I added firebase into my project using a different bundle identifier than in my iTunes connect app file, what should I do? It won't allow me to archive my app even when I change the identifier as the same in iTunes connect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the bundle identifier of an existing app — where "existing" means that the developer Member Center (the Portal) and/or App Store Connect knows about the app. The bundle identifier *is* the app; that's why it's call an *identifier*.

So, if you change the bundle identifier in Xcode, it's no longer the same app. You don't have any provisioning profile to develop it on a device (though you might get away with that if you have a wild-card profile). You don't have any provisioning profile to archive it. You have no entry for it at App Store Connect. It's not in the App Store. It is a *different app*, just as if you had started a new project in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by copying and pasting the bundle ID from iTunes connect to Xcode and "add another app" on firebase with that same Bundle ID